# Nuxt production build not including Global and Module CSS

Tags: css, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js

I am trying to use Chartist and Font-Awesome in my Nuxt project and need to include Chartist's CSS and the Font-Awesome module to do so. I have, [as per docs](https://nuxtjs.org/examples/global-css/), added the CSS file to my assets/css folder and in my nuxt.config file had added the reference in my CSS options:

```
...
 css: ['~/assets/css/chartist.css'],
...
```

as well as including my Font-Awesome module:

```
modules: [
   ...
    [
      'nuxt-fontawesome',
      {
        imports: [
          {
            set: '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons',
            icons: ['fas']
          },
          {
            set: '@fortawesome/free-brands-svg-icons',
            icons: ['fab']
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  ],
```

Everything looks great in dev but when I generate the project with the standard `npm run build` and then I serve the contents of the `/dist` folder the CSS for Chartist is missing and the Font-Awesome Icons will show up on the screen for a split second and then disappear, which leads me to think that their styling is not being loaded properly either.

I have seen this issue be discussed [in this Github post from 3 years ago](https://github.com/nuxt/nuxt.js/issues/278) but I am just building following the default folder structure so I do not think I would have to change anything with the default build settings.

Where might I have gone wrong?

Comment: Did you include the Font Awesome CSS? There are several stylesheets included with the package that should either be included in your main CSS file or attached like the chartist.css

Comment: No I used the npm version so I just installed it as a module. Chartist I actually downloaded the css. They both work locally, just not when I serve up the /dist folder from npm run build

Comment: Then I assume that webpack isn't copying everything for some reason... Usually a path issue in my experience. I've only ever tried that full include with SCSS so it needs a few additional things to compile and process the styles. I think FontAwesome has instructions for VUE. You might want to see what they say about styles.

Comment: Okay makes sense, but it wouldn't account for Chartist but it is a place to start looking, thanks!

Comment: I would agree. But maybe it will trigger something that solves both. Because as far as I can tell you're doing it correctly but Nuxt does some strange stuff on occasion.

Comment: @av0000 did you ever solve your problem?